# Set the value from another sheet. With a test of condition. Excel

Tags: powerpivot, libreoffice-calc

I have a table with two sheets. On the first (1) the name is written, on the second (2) Imin and numerical meaning are written, the same name can be written several times. There are also names that are not present on the sheet (1).

**Sheet 1.**

A

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Vova-- |  |
| Ben |  |

**Sheet 2.**

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Ben + | 2 |
| Timmy | 1 |
| Ben T | 4 |
| Vova | 6 |

How to put in the first sheet the sum of the values from the sheet (2)

I tried:

```
=IF(ColA2 = $Sheet2 ColA2; $Sheet2 ColB2)
=VLOOKUP(A1;$Sheet2.B2:B4;2)
=SUMIF($'Sheet2'A1:A4;A1;$'Sheet2'ColB1:ColB4)
```

1. Not work
2. Does not summarize the value
3. Looking for accurate coincidences

Names can end in different ways ...
Ben = Ben T

Required:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Vova-- | 6 |
| Ben | 3 |

Need help please.

Comment: =SUMIF($'Sheet2'A1:A4;LEFTB(A1;4)&"*";$'Sheet2'ColB1:ColB4)

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer. I need to use `LEFTB`

```
=SUMIF($'Sheet2'A1:A4;LEFTB(A1;4)&"*";$'Sheet2'ColB1:ColB4)
```

or

```
=SUMPRODUCT((LEFTB($Sheet2!$A$1:$A$4;3)=A2)*$Sheet2!B2:B5)
```